# Django: "distinct" alternatives for non-PostgreSQL databases

Tags: django, database, django-models, distinct

Consider the following model:

```
class Test(Model):
    # Some fields...

class TestExecution(Model):
    test = ForeignKey(Test)
    execution_date = DateTimeField()
    # more fields...

class Goal(Model):
    tests = ManyToManyField(Test)
    # more fields...
```

I want to get all the latest result of each test performed as part of a certain goal, so I perform the following query:

```
TestExecution.objects.filter(test__goal_id=goal_id).order_by("execution_date")
```

but the problem is that I get **ALL** the executions performed, and I want only the latest for each test.

I saw that the `distinct(*fields)` method can be used to eliminate duplicate execution of the same test, but it only works in PostgreSQL, so it is not suitable for me.

Is there any other way to filter a QuerySet so that it'll include only rows that are distinct on selected columns?

Answer (score -1):

You can remove duplicates not by a query, but sth like `list(set(list_of_objects))` (I recommend first check if it works), for removing list_of_objects duplicates you'll need to define a uniqueness of an object.
In order to do that, you'll need to make the object hashable. You need to define both **hash** and **eq** method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.execution_date==other.execution_date\
           and self.title==other.title
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(('title', self.title,
                 'execution_date', self.execution_date))
```

also you can do that more easily but not in clean way by getting `values_list` in query:

```
list(set(TestExecution.objects.filter(test__goal_id=goal_id)
                      .values_list("sth", flat = True)
                      .order_by("execution_date")))
```

if objects are not [hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable) remove in the dirty way:

```
seen_titles = set()
new_list = []
for obj in myList:
    if obj.title not in seen_titles:
        new_list.append(obj)
        seen_titles.add(obj.title)
```

Comment: Not good in any way: QuerySet are lazy, and I want to keep that feature.

Comment: I'd like to know the solution, let me know about that if you found out